# Simple Client-Server Application - Socket problems

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm writing a simple client-server application using TCP Sockets . It works with the multi-threading principle to allow for several client connections to the same server.

I'm having some trouble figuring out some of the errors I get with the sockets, i'm fairly new in this environment as you will probably tell.

I'll show you the code I have, and the output i get from it, but basically the problem lies in the very connecting of the clients to the server, and I ran through all the code but still can't find what's wrong with it.

Server:

```
public static ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
public static int index;
public static String date;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {//inicio main      


    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6500);   //Create socket on port 6500
    System.out.println ("Server started on port 6500");     
    while (true){   //Waiting for clients
        System.out.println("Server waiting for client connections..");
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\UNIV\\Redes\\workspace\\Copy of Ex_4.3_Teste\\lists\\blacklist.txt"));
        String line = null;
        socket = server.accept();

        // Blacklist verification
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals(socket.getInetAddress().toString())) {
                System.out.println("IP Blacklisted: " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                System.out.println("Closing connection to " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                PrintStream checkBlack = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                checkBlack.println("***BLACKLISTED***");
                reader.close();
                checkBlack.close();
                socket.close();
                break; 
            }
        }//End of Blacklist Verification

        //Sending feedback in case of approved client
        try { 
        PrintStream checkBlack = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        checkBlack.println("***NBLACKLISTED***");
        checkBlack.close();
        } catch (SocketException e) {

        }
        userList.add(socket.getInetAddress().toString()); //Add connected user's IP to USERLIST
        System.out.println("New connection..");
        System.out.println("Size of UserList: " + userList.size());
        Thread t = new Thread(new EchoClientThread(socket)); 

        t.start(); //Starting Client Thread


    }//End of Waiting for Clients       
}//End of Main  

public static class EchoClientThread implements Runnable{
    private Socket s;
    public EchoClientThread(Socket socket) {
        this.s = socket;
    }
    public void run() { 
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();   //Thread Name
        String stringClient = s.getInetAddress().toString();    //Client IP
        System.out.println("Connected to " + stringClient); 

        try{                
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));         
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(
                    s.getOutputStream(),true);
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) !=null) {  //Input Cycle   

                System.out.println (stringClient+": "+threadName+": "+line);    //Print command from client

                if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("9")){ //Exit
                    break;
                }

                else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){   //Send List of Online Users
                    System.out.println("Option 1: Sending list of online users to " + stringClient);
                    output.println(" ");
                    output.println("List of Online Users:");
                    output.println(" ");
                    for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++){
                        output.println(userList.get(i));
                    }
                }

                else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {  //Send message to a single user
                    System.out.println("Nothing here yet..");
                }

                else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {  //Send message to all the online users
                    System.out.println("Nothing here yet..");
                }

                else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("4")){   //Send User Blacklist
                    System.out.println("Option 4: Sending user blacklist to " + stringClient);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\UNIV\\Redes\\workspace\\Copy of Ex_4.3_Teste\\lists\\blacklist.txt"));
                    String lineRead = null;
                    output.println(" ");
                    output.println("User Blacklist:");
                    output.println(" ");
                    while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        output.println(lineRead);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                }

                else{
                    output.println("Unknown command.");
                }   

                output.println("***CLOSE***");  //Closes client's input cycle
                output.println("***NBLACKLISTED***");   //Sending feedback in case of approved client                       
            }//Input Cycle End

            output.println("See you later!"); 
            input.close();  //Closes inputStream 
            output.close(); //Closes outputStream
            s.close();  //Closes Socket                         
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Server Side Error!");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        userList.remove(s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("Client "+ stringClient+" was disconnected!");                   
    }//End of run()  
}//End of EchoClientThread
}//End of EchoServerThread
```

Client:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    if (args.length !=1){
        System.err.println ("usage: java EchoClient2 <host>");
        System.exit(1);
    }               
    String host = args[0];
    int port = 6500;
    String cmd, line;
    Socket socket = new Socket(host,port);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

        while( true ) {//Input cycle 

            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            if (input.readLine().equals("***BLACKLISTED***")) {
                System.out.println("IP is Blacklisted");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("CLIENT MENU");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("1 - List on-line users");
            System.out.println("2 - Send message to a single user");
            System.out.println("3 - Send message to all on-line users");
            System.out.println("4 - List Blacklisted Users");
            System.out.println("9 - Exit");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print(host+":"+port+"#>");   //Command prompt            
            cmd = scan.nextLine();  //Scanning command to send to the server    
            output.println(cmd);    //Sending command to the server

            if ( cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("9")){
                System.out.println("Exiting..");
                break;
            } 

            try {
            while (!(line = input.readLine()).equals("***CLOSE***")) {  //Input Cycle                           
            System.out.println (line);  //Prints server answer      
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Client Side Error!");
                System.out.println(e);
                break;
            }

        }//End of Cycle

    System.out.println("Connection Terminated");
    input.close();  //Closes inputStream
    output.close(); //Closes outputStream
    socket.close(); //Closes Socket 
}
}
```

So the server starts fine with the following output:

```
Server started on port 6500
Server waiting for client connections..
```

But as soon as I try to connect with the client, this happens:

Server Side:

```
Server started on port 6500
Server waiting for client connections..
New connection..
Size of UserList: 1
Server waiting for client connections..
Connected to /127.0.0.1
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
Server Side Error!
Client /127.0.0.1 was disconnected!
```

On the client side, though, it still shows the input menu, and the command prompt, like so:

```
CLIENT MENU

1 - List on-line users
2 - Send message to a single user
3 - Send message to all on-line users
4 - List Blacklisted Users
9 - Exit

127.0.0.1:6500#>
```

And when I input something on the Client Side prompt, i get:

```
127.0.0.1:6500#>1
Client Side Error!
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Connection Terminated
```

I know what the errors mean, `Socket is closed` is pretty much self-explanatory, but i just can't find wheres the code problem that makes the socket close.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your server code? It looks to me your server simply closed the socket because of exception. If you can post the exception also that will help

Comment: The only exception I get is `java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed` when a client tries to connect to the server. Debugging didn't help me though, thats partly why I asked this here. Apparently it closes the socket right after the `System.out.println("Connected to "+ stringClient)` but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your blacklist mechanism not quite right.

When you close a stream associated with the socket it will close the socket as well.

So the server is closing any socket that it gets and then hands it on to a thread,
which tries to use the socket and fails.

```
    // Blacklist verification
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // blah blah blah
    }//End of Blacklist Verification

    //Sending feedback in case of approved client
    try { 
        PrintStream checkBlack = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        checkBlack.println("***NBLACKLISTED***");
        checkBlack.close();  // <== why are you closing the stream?
    } catch (SocketException e) {

    }
```

try this instead

```
    // Blacklist verification
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // blah blah blah
    }//End of Blacklist Verification

    //Sending feedback in case of approved client
    try { 
        socket.getOutputStream().write("***NBLACKLISTED***\n".getBytes());
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A debugger is your friend.

Comment: I thought I needed to close the Stream in order to open a new one for the commands input. Well, I guess not then. Every day is a learning day ^^ Thanks a bunch.

Comment: PrintStream wraps around the SocketStream so you can just leave it hanging. Don't close unless you want the underlying stream to close. Streams can get confusing some you have to close others you have to leave alone.

Comment: Oh I see, and doing `socket.getOutputStream().write()` just writes what it has to write to and closes the Stream without closing the Socket ?

Comment: No the stream stays open. When you create the socket you create an upstream(out) and a downstream(in). There can only ever be one of each so they need to stay open for the life of the socket. When you need to send or receive something you just get the appropriate Stream and read or write. Whenever you call get***Stream on the socket you will get the same stream for ***, which is important if you have multiple threads using the same socket. When the socket closes the streams will get cleaned up for you.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing, but i think i got it now, thanks for taking the time :)